# Autofac DI .NET MVC controllers without default constructor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, constructor, dependency-injection, controller, autofac

When I use Ajax queries to ASP.NET MVC Controller I have a error: Type 'Web.Implementation.Controllers.MyController' does not have a default constructor.

My code:

```
    //In My Controller

    private IDataService DataService;

    //I try to delete this constructor, 
    //because I use DI and don't want to create a CurrentContext and DataService.
    public MyController()
    {
       var CurrentContext = new CurrentContext();
       DataService = new DataService(CurrentContext);
    }

    public MyController(IDataService dataService)
    {
        DataService = dataService;
    }

    //In Autofac Init
    builder.RegisterType<DataService>().As <IDataService>();
```

How I can use Autofac DI in this case ?
Help me please.

UPD:

```
//in Global.asax
DependencyConfigure.Initialize();

//in DependencyConfigure class
 public static void Initialize()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(
                new Dependency(RegisterServices(builder))
                );
        }
```

Comment: Di you at least google it? https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MvcIntegration3

Comment: Yes, thanks, I wrote builder.RegisterType<MyController>().InstancePerHttpRequest() in autofac init, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you set up the dependency resolver with `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));`?

Comment: I call initialize functionf from global.asax